# Why this scala code reports compilation error: recursive value x needs type

Tags: scala, type-inference

The scala code is simple:

```
case class X(id: Option[String] = None, username: Option[String])

object X {
  def create(x: X): X = {
    x.copy(id = Some("111"))
  }
}

class Test {

  def test() {
    val x = X.create(X(
      username = Some("Hello, world!")))

    val id = x.id.get  // !!! reports: recursive value x needs type
  }

}
```

Please note the line:

```
 val id = x.id.get
```

Why it reports `recursive value x needs type`?

If I change the variable name, as:

```
val dd = x.id.get
```

It will be OK.

PS: scala version is:  2.9.1.final

Comment: Interesting... I've just tweeted it, in case of... http://bit.ly/zU52GP

Comment: Submitted: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5434

Comment: Actually that's a duplicate of [SI-5091](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5091) ... you should add this example to that ticket.

Comment: Yes, but that issue was submitted at 19/Oct/11, that was 4 months ago. Nobody cares about it.

Comment: You won't make the people who matter care more about bugs by creating duplicates of them, in fact most likely quite the opposite if your motivation it to attract attention. If you want a faster resolution add your new information to the original ticket, and/or provide a patch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Removing the default argument for `id` in the definition of case class `X` also fixes the problem which suggests that this is an instance of [SI-5091](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5091).